# Create associative array from three flat arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

Consider the following:

```
    $a = array('Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4');
    $b = array('2014' => '101', '2014' => '102', '2014' => '103', '2014' => '104');
    $c = array('2015' => '101', '2015' => '102', '2015' => '103', '2015' => '104');
```

How do I transform these 3 arrays into one like this:

```
    array(
        'Q1' => array(
            '2014' => '101',
            '2015' => '101'
        ),
        'Q2' => array(
            '2014' => '102',
            '2015' => '102'
        ),
        'Q3' => array(
            '2014' => '103',
            '2015' => '103'
        ),
        'Q4' => array(
            '2014' => '104',
            '2015' => '104'
        )
    );
```

I'm unable to properly merge `$b` and `$c` in a way that I can use `array_combine` with `$a` maintaining the desired structure as mentioned above.

Sorry for the `array()` all over the code, I'm dealing with a legacy app.

Comment: Your `$b` and `$c` arrays aren't going to be much use like that - you can't have duplicate keys in a PHP array.

Comment: @user2094178, can you edit your question with valid input arrays?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Sorry for that, this was a stupid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have duplicate Array Keys and in this case, the very last Key would override the Preceding ones. Here, an arbitrary assumption was made to the effect that the keys have unique suffixes so as to facilitate the merging you had intended.

```
<?php

    $a = array('Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4');
    $b = array('2014' => '101', '2014_2' => '102', '2014_3' => '103', '2014_4' => '104');
    $c = array('2015' => '101', '2015_2' => '102', '2015_3' => '103', '2015_4' => '104');

    function mergeArraysAssociative($arrKeys, $array1, $array2) {
        $merged = array();
        foreach ($arrKeys as $key => $val) {
            $arrKeys1   = array_keys($array1);
            $arrKeys2   = array_keys($array2);

            $arrValues1 = array_values($array1);
            $arrValues2 = array_values($array2);

            $merged[$val][$arrKeys1[$key]] = $arrValues1[$key];
            $merged[$val][$arrKeys2[$key]] = $arrValues2[$key];

        }

        return $merged;
    }

    var_dump(mergeArraysAssociative($a, $b, $c));

?>
```

> The var_dump() above produces something similar to what is shown below. And, you can [quick test it here](https://eval.in/611668).

```
array (size=4)
  'Q1' => 
    array (size=2)
      2014 => string '101' (length=3)
      2015 => string '101' (length=3)
  'Q2' => 
    array (size=2)
      '2014_2' => string '102' (length=3)
      '2015_2' => string '102' (length=3)
  'Q3' => 
    array (size=2)
      '2014_3' => string '103' (length=3)
      '2015_3' => string '103' (length=3)
  'Q4' => 
    array (size=2)
      '2014_4' => string '104' (length=3)
      '2015_4' => string '104' (length=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
<?php
    $d = array();
    for($i=0; $i<count($a), $++){
        $d[$a[$i]][] = $b[$i];
        $d[$a[$i]][] = $c[$i];
    }
    print_r($d)
?>
```